# Menú desplegable en telefono no se cierra (jquery)

Tags: jquery

Tengo un problemilla con el menú desplegable de una web, al darle al menú hamburguesa, se despliega perfectamente y salen las categorías correctamente, pero al hacer click sobre alguna de ellas el menú no se repliega. Estoy seguro que es alguna tontería que me he dejado en el código. 
Os dejo la porción de código que donde debe estar el problema.

```
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
   $('.menu-icon').on('click', function() {
     $('nav').slideToggle();  
   })
```

Muchisimas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que tu condición no se active nunca. Comprueba el tamaño de la pantalla con:

```
console.log($(window).width());
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la condición si que se activa, de hecho el problema se da cuando emulo un teléfono móvil con el navegador o desde el mismo móvil.
Para replegar el menú, hay que dar de nuevo en el botón de menú hamburguesa.

Comment: Solucionado!!

El código hacia referencia solo al icono del menú, no al menú en si.